# Nginx and relative path

Tags: url, nginx, relative-path

On nginx root we have such files:

```
   - test\
       image.jpg
       index.html
   - ...
```

There is  link to the image.jpg  at index.html:

```
<img src='image.jpg'>
```

In standard Nginx config we have such lines (http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

```
   server {
    server_name example.com;
    ...
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html;
   }
```

For URL http://example.com/test/index.html (and for http://example.com/test/ ) all will work well, because base for relative path will be http://example.com/test/  and we have image.jpg in this folder.

For http://example.com/test page will be shown, but without image.

What is the best solution in this case?

Comment: In this case best solution would be use `index index.html;` directive instead of `try_files`. In that case nginx will redirect from `/test` to `/test/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean `$uri` with a **I** and not `$url` with an **L**.

The problem is that `try_files` will source the file at `$uri/index.html` but leave the URI as `/test` so any relative URIs will be relative to `/` and not `/test/`.

If you are going to use relative URIs within your HTML files, you must enforce the trailing `/` on directory references. For example:

```
index index.html;
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

This will cause `/test` to redirect to `/test/` and the `index` directive will automatically try the `index.html` file within the sub directory.